# No Add-In Tab Though Add-In is Loaded and Working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I wrote an Excel VBA add-in over ten years ago, which uses the old Commandbars to put a menu in Excel's Tools menu (in Excel 2003 and earlier) or in Excel's Add-Ins tab (in Excel 2007 and later). I've never had a problem with the menu appearing, in all versions of Excel from 97 through 2013.

But now a user says Excel Add-Ins menu not appearing for him in Excel 2013. Normally that means the add-in isn't loaded, but in his case the add-in is loaded and working. We know the add-in is loaded and working because the add-in adds user-defined worksheet functions, and those UDFs are working fine for him. But he wants to get to the add-in's menu and can't.

My googling showed that some people are having trouble with the Add-Ins menu in 2013, but I didn't find anything specific to this problem.

Yes, he's tried enabling the Add-Ins tab in Excel Options > Customize the Ribbon.

BTW this is an .xla add-in, not a COM add-in.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

I have Excel 2010 and had the add-in tab disappear for MrExcel HTML add-in.  I tried all types of suggestions - and finally found one that worked for me!

Go to the add-ins folder where you have your add in saved.  Right click on the file, and select Properties.  At the bottom of the General tab - if it says "Security" - check on the "Unblock" option.

Voila!  My add-ins never disappear anymore!

Comment: This worked for me --- thanks very much!  (Excel 2010 x64 - add-in showed as loaded but the tab didn't appear.  No error messages, even with Show Addin UI Errors checked.)

Answer (score 4):

Solved:

Solved this now but really weird solution if you enabled the Add-in whilst the Analysis ToolPaks were enabled it'd have the issue you above, but if you enabled the Add-in whilst the Analysis ToolPaks weren't ticked then went back in to it and re-ticked the Analysis ToolPaks it'd be fine and wouldn't disappear!
Was an extremely strange issue!

See [Spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/457676-excel-2013-add-ins-tab-keeps-disappearing-from-ribbon)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood this is a problem with Excel 2013 (another attempt of the guys at Redmond to make our lives miserable with every update of their products). The workaround I've found is to include the following code into the ThisWorkbook module of the Addin:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Workbook_AddinUninstall
    Workbook_AddinInstall

End Sub
```

Cheers!

Comment: Works beautifully, though I had to change to -> Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Comment: Do you also have `Workbook_AddinUninstall` and `Workbook_AddinInstall` event procedures in the ThisWorkbook module? Because if not, it makes no sense. These lines of code don't install or uninstall the add-in, they call other procedures that run when the add-in is installed or uninstalled.

Comment: Of course you have to define those procedures @JonPeltier. In those you create and destroy the menus. And sizeight was right, the procedure should be Workbook_Open() instead of Thisworkbook_Open(). I edited the comment to fix it.

Comment: Just clarifying. In the old days, when I had custom menus and toolbars, I handled them in Workbook_Open and _BeforeClose, which fire even when the workbook is an add-in. Having them in the _AddIn-related procedures was redundant. If you went with a custom ribbon, this wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with excel 2013. Add-in tab was missing. I went to Developer>>>Add-Ins and deselected the add-in I wanted. Click OK then repeat the process and select the same add-in. Click OK. The Add-In tab should appear.

Comment: Your solution works, for sure. But do you have an idea *why* it works? Or rather: What causes the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

See also https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/add-in-ribbon-disappears/

As of july 2016 the security settings in Excel disable the add-ins in the old default location. THe website shows how to set the directory to trusted status

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where two .xlam files that loaded and appeared in custom ribbon tabs in Excel 2010 didn't show up in the ribbon in Excel 2013 even though they were loading each time a workbook was opened.  I tried all sorts of solutions - disabling the Analysis Toolpack, disabling and enabling the .xlam files, making sure the .xlam's attached XML file was up to date (I was thinking an MSO image I had in the XML code was no longer available in Excel 2013), but nothing worked.  I eventually tried copying and renaming the .xlam file and enabled it in Excel and, strangely, it appeared in the ribbon.

I have no idea why it needed to be copied and renamed - it's almost like Excel 2013 needed a fresh copy of the .xlam file before it could show up.  Very weird!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this answer for a LONG time and the previous code worked, but, for me, only with Workbook_Open() instead of Thisworkbook_Open()

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbook_AddinUninstall
    Workbook_AddinInstall
End Sub
```

Thanks for finding this!

Comment: As I asked above, do you also have `Workbook_AddinUninstall` and `Workbook_AddinInstall` event procedures in the ThisWorkbook module?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the add-ins via the Developer tab, and then enabled them via File>Options>Add-Ins>Manage Add-Ins.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

You  can Try by disabling macros with notification.  (tried on 2016)

1. File->options->trust center->macro settings-> tick disable all macros with notification 
   It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

If I disabled and enabled, I could get the Add-Ins tab to appear, but every time I opened a document I had to repeat. This seemed to fix it for me:

File > Options > AddIns > Choose "XML Expansion Packs" > Go > Select "Microsoft Action Pane 3" > Attach > Ok

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with Excel 2016 (not with 2010 and 2017), and very strangely it was solved this way :

1) Desactivating the add-in
2) Quitting Excel
3) Activating the add-in
4) Going to File > Close (in French version : Fichier > Fermer)

And when I click "Close" the "Components" menu suddenly appear in Excel 2016 !

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in Excel 2010. Tried all the suggestions above, but to no avail. In the end it turned out that even though it was an .xll add-in, it somehow also was listed as a COM add-in. So going to File > Options > Add-In, then selecting Disabled Items from the list at the bottom of that window and enabling the add-in, worked for me. Now in the list of Active Application Add-ins it shows both the original Excel Add-in, and the unexpected COM add-in without location. Oh, and the tab is back of course. Go figure.